# Dropdown is not showing up in Kendo grid inline editing mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I would like to show a Kendo dropdown in a Kendo grid cell when user click on it to Edit.

This is my code `index.cshtml` file grid code

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SvwDesignMaterialSystemAttributeDto>()
        .Name("DesignMaterialSystemAttribute")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(m => m.MaxAcceptableValue).Hidden();

            columns.Bound(m => m.MaxAcceptableText).ClientTemplate(
                "# if (MaxAcceptableText) { #"
                    + "#=formatValueInUnit(MaxAcceptableText, UnitTypeCode)#" + " "
                + "# } #").Title("Max").Width(100);

        })
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Save();
    })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)).Pageable().Sortable()
    .Events(e => e.Edit("onEdit"))

    .Events(events => events.DataBound("function"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(m => m.DesignMaterialSystemAttributeId);
            .....
        })
        .Events(events => events.DataBound(
                    @<text>
                    function (e) {
                        if ($('#DesignMaterialSystemAttribute').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data().length == 0) {
                            $("#DesignMaterialSystemAttribute").find('tbody')
                                .append('<tr class="kendo-data-row"><td colspan="6" style="text-align: center"><b>No Results Found!</b></td></tr>');
                        }
                    }
                    </text>
        ))
        .AutoBind(true)
)
```

This is edit click event inside  tag the same file `index.cshtml`

```
<script id="myscript" type="text/javascript">

function onEdit(e)
{ 
    var field = e.sender.columns[e.container.index()].field;
    if (e.model.UnitTypeCode === "UNIT_LOOKUP_COMBOBOX") {

       var input = $("<input id='products'/>")    

       $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#products").kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: "ProductName",
                dataValueField: "ProductID",
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            dataType: "jsonp",
                            url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products",
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });             

        var temp = $("#products");
        e.container.append(input);
        input.focus();

        temp.remove();
        kendo.bind(e.container, e.model);
    }
}

</script>
```

I have taken above code kendo [Kendo dropdown example](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/remotedatasource). When I click on cell it just shows `Textbox` (input) on the grid cell in edit mode not dropdown.

[image]

This is how I want to do [dropdown in grid inline editing.](https://codepen.io/jordanilchev/pen/DwNLVg)

In the first link there are few kendo styles being used, I added those and got warning in console regarding kendo subscription. Seems those styles are new release `2023.1.117`. I dont want update kendo subscription. I just want to go with current subscription.

How can I add Kendo dropdown to grid inline editing mode ?

**Edit 1:**

Here in the second if condition I need dropdown, by following 2nd approach how can I do it

```
 <script id="myscript" type="text/javascript">
    
    function onEdit(e)
    {
        var field = e.sender.columns[e.container.index()].field;
        if (e.model.UnitTypeCode === "Integer") {
          //other editor control
        }
        if (e.model.UnitTypeCode === "UNIT_LOOKUP_COMBOBOX") {
        
          //here I need dropdown editor
        
        }
        if (e.model.UnitTypeCode === "Float") {
        //other editor control
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Edit 2** I am able to do it with `HTML` dropdown but not `kendo`

```
 if (e.model.UnitTypeCode === "UNIT_LOOKUP_COMBOBOX") {

                var dataItem = $("#DesignMaterialSystemAttribute").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.get(e.model.DesignMaterialSystemAttributeId);
                var unitCodeTypeRow = dataItem.UnitLookupCodeType;
                var maxAcceptableValueRow = dataItem.MaxAcceptableText;

                var input = $("<select style='outline:none; width:100%' name='MaxAcceptableName' data-value-update='MaxAcceptableText' data-bind='text: MaxAcceptableText' id='MaxAcceptableId'></select > ")
                var dataDdl = null;
                var maxAcceptableText = null;
                var maxAcceptableValue = null;

                var grid = $("#DesignMaterialSystemAttribute").data("kendoGrid");
                var data = grid.dataSource.data();
                var gridRowTr = grid.dataItem($(e.container).closest("tr"));
                var currentRowIndex = data.indexOf(gridRowTr);

                jQuery(document).ready(function () {

                    var lookUpCodeUrl = '@Url.Action("GetCodesList", "LookupCode")';

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: lookUpCodeUrl,
                    })
                        .success(function (responseData) {

                            dataDdl = responseData;
                            var selectedCellItemValue = data[currentRowIndex].MaxAcceptableValue;
                            var cellItemIndex = responseData.findIndex(x => x.CodeLovId == selectedCellItemValue);
                            if (cellItemIndex !== -1) {
                                responseData.unshift(...responseData.splice(cellItemIndex, 1));
                            }

                            $("#MaxAcceptableId").empty();
                            $.each(responseData, function (i, v) {
                                $("#MaxAcceptableId").append($('<option/>', {
                                    value: v.CodeLovId,
                                    text: v.Description
                                }));
                            })
                        })

                }(jQuery));

                $('tr').off('td').off('change').on('change', '#MaxAcceptableId', function () {
                    maxAcceptableText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
                    maxAcceptableValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
                    var oldModel = e.sender.dataSource._pristineForModel(e.model);
                    if (maxAcceptableValue != "" & maxAcceptableValue != undefined) {
                        data[currentRowIndex].set("MaxAcceptableValue", maxAcceptableValue);
                        if (data[currentRowIndex].MaxAcceptableValue == oldModel.MaxAcceptableValue) {
                            e.model.dirty = false;
                            e.container.removeClass("k-dirty-cell");
                        }
                    }
                    if (maxAcceptableText != "" & maxAcceptableText != undefined) {
                        data[currentRowIndex].set("MaxAcceptableText", maxAcceptableText);
                        if (data[currentRowIndex].MaxAcceptableText == oldModel.MaxAcceptableText) {
                            e.model.dirty = false;
                            e.container.removeClass("k-dirty-cell");
                        }
                    }
                });

                

                $("#DesignMaterialSystemAttribute").bind("change", function (args) {

                    var selectedCellItemValue = data[currentRowIndex].MaxAcceptableValue;
                    var cellItemIndex = dataDdl.findIndex(x => x.CodeLovId == selectedCellItemValue);
                    if (cellItemIndex !== -1) {
                        dataDdl.unshift(...dataDdl.splice(cellItemIndex, 1));
                    }

                    $("#MaxAcceptableId").empty();
                    $.each(dataDdl, function (i, v) {
                        $("#MaxAcceptableId").append($('<option/>', {
                            value: v.CodeLovId,
                            text: v.Description
                        }));
                    })
                });

                var temp = $("#MaxAcceptableText");
                e.container.append(input);
                input.focus();

                temp.remove();
                kendo.bind(e.container, e.model);
            }
```

Comment: Maybe the library isn't loaded. You are referencing the static styles and script files right?

Comment: I refenced those in Console it says something about Kendo subscription. I think may be they latest as showing in the names 2023.1.117. I just want to do it with existing subscription.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to the Editors and editor templates there is a slight difference in how the Grid works depending on whether the HTML wrappers or Kendo UI is used.

When using the HTML wrappers (UI for ASP.NET Core or UI for ASP.NET MVC) the editors used are those located in the ~/Viwes/Shared/EditorTemplates folder. Those templates are serialized and passed as a [columns.editor](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.editor) as a string and this way define the Editor when the cell enters edit mode.  You can specify the editor to be used via the [`EditorTemplateName` configuration](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/api/kendo.mvc.ui.fluent/gridboundcolumnbuilder#editortemplatenamesystemstring).

Initializing the Grid using Kendo UI you can set the [editor](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.editor) to the desired widget (or use a function that returns the editor) and use [editorOptions](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.editoroptions) to provide additional configuration options.

Now, to create a custom editor when you us HTML helpers, for example a DropDownList for a column, rather than a TextBox follow the [example on custom editing](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/grid/editing-custom) and the [docs](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/html-helpers/data-management/grid/editing/custom). Basically you have to:

1. Decorate the model property with [UIHint] attribute:

   ```
    [UIHint("ClientCategory")]
    public CategoryViewModel Category {get;set;}
   ```
2. Create the custom editor and place it in ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates folder

   ```
   @model Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.CategoryViewModel

   @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
        .DataValueField("CategoryID")
        .DataTextField("CategoryName")
        .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["categories"]) //You can also bind to a DataSource, it's not mandatory to use local data
   )
   ```
3. Add the column definition:

   ```
   columns.Bound(p => p.Category).ClientTemplate("#=Category.CategoryName#").Width(180);
   ```

   The [ClientTemplate](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/api/kendo.mvc.ui.fluent/gridboundcolumnbuilder#clienttemplatesystemstring) configuration is used to show a property of the CategoryViewModel, as otherwise you will see [Object object] on the Grid

Now, if for some reason you do not want to use an EditorTemplate from the EditorTemplates folder and desire to use a JS function to initialize an editor for a column you can define a function that returns the editor and on document.ready use the setOptions method of the Grid to override the options and set the function to the columns.editor configuration - [example](https://netcorerepl.telerik.com/QdOmcyFw457l5qmo42)

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ProductViewModel>()
.Name("grid")
.AutoBind(false)
.Columns(columns => {
    columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
    ...
    columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(150);
})
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
...
)

<script type="text/javascript">
 function productNameEditor(container, options) {
        $('<input required name="' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                autoBind:false,
                dataTextField: "ProductName",
                dataValueField: "ProductName",
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: "@Url.Action("RemoteDataSource_GetProducts", "DropDownList")",
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }
    $("document").ready(function(){
        var grid = $("#grid").getKendoGrid();
        var options = grid.options;
        options.columns[0].editor = productNameEditor;
        grid.setOptions(options);
        grid.dataSource.read();
    })
</script>
```

**Edit:**

To extend on the second approach - using a conditional editor for each column is also possible and you can call a function which based on the conditions you have will return the desired editor.

Iterate all the columns and assign the editor to the function returning the desired editor. `options.field` represents the field for which the editor will be generated when you click on a cell, and you can access the model that is being edited via `options.model` :

```
   $("document").ready(function(){
        var grid = $("#grid").getKendoGrid();
        var options = grid.options;
        options.columns.forEach((itm)=>itm.editor = chooseEditor)
        grid.setOptions(options);
        grid.dataSource.read();
      })

   function chooseEditor(container, options) {
    switch (options.field) {
        case "ProductName":
            if(options.model.ProductID % 2 == 0){
                dropdownEditor(container, options);
            } else {
                textEditor(container, options);
            }
            break;
        case "UnitPrice":
            currencyEditor(container, options);
            break;
        case "UnitsInStock":
            numericEditor(container, options);
            break;
        case "OrderDate":
            dateEditor(container, options);
            break;
        case "Discontinued":
            booleanEditor(container, options);
            break;
        default:
            textEditor(container, options);
            break;
     }
   }
```

The functions will return the respective editor, for example:

```
  function textEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input type="text" name="' + options.field + '"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoTextBox()  
  }

  function numericEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input name="' + options.field + '"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoNumericTextBox()
}
```

So based on the above, in [this updated example](https://netcorerepl.telerik.com/mdOwQLFn17Oc9IaX23) clicking on cells in the ProductName column will [render either a DropDownList or a TextBox](https://screenrec.com/share/pqdreKnS0s).

Comment: I am following 2nd approach, I have few quetions
`1)` How to give particular column and cell option here `options.columns[0].editor`
`2)` I need ddl editor on particular condition, please check in `Edit 1`. Where do I need to write code, in the same if condition as Edit1?
`3)` In this link (`columns.editor configuration - example`) I can't see dropdown in grid ?

Comment: I've updated the answer to address the questions. 1) iterate all the [columns](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/fields/columns) and set the editor as a function, which will conditionally return the editor. 2) Check the ProductName case - based on the ProductID either a TextBox or a DropDownList is generated for an editor. 3) You need to [click on a cell](https://screenrec.com/share/pqdreKnS0s) for it to enter edit mode and the editor to be generated

Comment: With `onEdit(e)` method many things has already been developed. So would like to go with that way.  Just want to know how can I do this way `e.container.append(input);` (as given in my code above).  So instead of using Editor function name, just call it and append on the next line like( `var mycontrol = textEditor()` ) but here the problem will be we do not have `options`, we have `container`. So I hope you are getting what I am trying to say. So could please generate `netcorerepl` with the same approach I have shown in my code with `onEdit(e) `generate control and `append`.

Comment: The way I am trying to do in question, I am able to do HTML dropdown but not kendo. HTML dropdown we don't want need kendo one. Please check my code with HTML working successfully. See `Edit 2`

Comment: I'd suggest against doing all this in the edit event handler. Reason is the editors will already be initialized, so you will need to destroy them and add the new once. With InCell editing this will result in closing the cell and the cellClose event will fire, and it is not preventable. To my knowledge the way to prevent the cell from closing is to fail the validation, for example making the inputs required. Even this way I still have issues with the initial binding, and also canceling the changes will not be possible.

Comment: Anyways, here is the [updated example](https://netcorerepl.telerik.com/mROwGCPc58EyKhQX24) and the closest I can get it to work. However I would still go the other way - assign the `chooseEditor` function as an editor for the columns where conditional editor is desired, execute any additional logic and return the desired editor.